# Finding mistake in application of Karamata's theorem (regularly varying functions)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

We call a function $L:(0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ **slowly varying** if $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{L(cx)}{L(x)}=1\ \forall c>0$. Notation: $L \in \mathcal L$.

We call a function $f$ **regularly varying** if $f(x)=\frac{L(x)}{x^\alpha}$ with $\alpha>0$ and $L$ slowly varying. Notation: $f$ in $\mathcal R_\alpha$

Theorem: $L$ is slowly varying if $L$ can be  written as $$L(x)=c(x)\exp\Bigg(\int_a^x\frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}dt\Bigg)$$ where $c(x)>0$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}c(x)>0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}\epsilon(t)=0$.

> Task: Let $\tilde c(x)>0$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\tilde c(x)>0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}\tilde\epsilon(t)=\alpha$. Show that

> $$(R(x)\mathrm{\ can\ be\ written\ as\ }R(x)=\tilde c(x)\exp\Bigg(\int_a^x\frac{\tilde \epsilon(t)}{t}dt\Bigg)) \Leftrightarrow R(x) \in \mathcal R_\alpha $$

I want to prove the '$\Rightarrow$' direction first.

We have that $R(x)\exp(\int_a^x-\frac{\alpha}{t}dt)=\tilde c(x)\exp\Bigg(\int_a^x\frac{\tilde \epsilon(t)-\alpha}{t}dt\Bigg)$ is slowly varying according to the theorem because $\tilde \epsilon(t)-\alpha$ converges to zero.
Now, $\exp(\int_a^x-\frac{\alpha}{t}dt)=\exp(\ln(\frac{x}{a})^{-\alpha})=(\frac{a}{x})^\alpha$, so we have that $L(x):=R(x)(\frac{a}{x})^\alpha$ is slowly varying.

Now, $R(x)=L(x)\frac{x^\alpha}{a^\alpha}$, but this would mean that $R(x) \in \mathcal R_{\color{red}-\alpha}$ instead of $R(x) \in \mathcal R_{\color{red}+\alpha}$. Where is my mistake?